# add column value to the row selected in gridview after clicking button send

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

Im filling my gridview in the code behind using (C#), I have one column called [SO_Status], This column is empty at the begining, I want to change the value of [SO_Status] to "SO already sent" when I click the button Send!

here is a capture of my grid view:
[image]

the select code is:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Int16 email;
    if ( e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        email = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);
        em.Text = GridView1.Rows[email].Cells[4].Text;
    }
}
public void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        ....
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "validation", "alert('Your Email was sent successfully!');", true);       
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("Sent error");
        }
    }
}
```

I use the select button to get the mail address from the line and send email to this mail address, I want to change the SO_Status after sending this email, to avoid sending email another time to the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the SO_Status in database and rebind the grid from database.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Int16 email;
        if ( e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            email = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);
            em.Text = GridView1.Rows[email].Cells[4].Text;
            //send the email
             if (Sendmail(em.Text))
             {
                updateStatus(em.Text);
                // rebind the grid. 
                bindgrid(); 
             }
             else
              {
               // write code to show error message.
              }
        }
    }






 private bool Sendmail( string email)
  {
    // code to send mail 
    // you can find the code on google.

   return returnvalue;
  }



 private void updateStatus(string email)
  {
    // Code to update db colomn
  }

   private void bindgrid()
  {
       // code to bind grid.
  }
```

Comment: update ["tablename"] set SO_Status=["value"] where email=["email"] you need to replace "tablename" with your database table name "value" to true or false or what ever type of your db column and "email" with the email address you have send the email.

Comment: How can I do the test with (if (sendMail..)) using my send button Code ??